# PSQL: Row locking via Select FOR UPDATE

Tags: sql, multithreading, postgresql, locking, psql

I am trying to implement locking via the database using the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` psql command https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html

I can't find much documentation around doing this, besides the fact that the command allows for database row based locking

I am wondering what happens if Thread 1 executes `SELECT FOR UPDATE` first, then Thread 2 comes shortly after and tries to execute the same command. Does Thread 2 get blocked, until the database transaction in Thread 1 commits or rollsback?

Comment: Why don't you try it?  Instead of threads, you can simulate this by opening 2 sessions to a PostgreSQL database, and executing the commands in sequence in a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Thread2 will be waiting until Thread1 is completed.

You can use `NOWAIT` or `SKIP LOCKS` to prevent the operation from waiting (see [SELECT in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html)).